How do you validate millions of data in 2 different databases as part of ETL Testing
How to validate millions of data in 2 different databases as part of ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) Testing.
And in the same databases, also tell me the testing process to validate the Target DWH (Data Warehouse).

I’m voting to close this question because this question seems more relevant for the DBA - https://dba.stackexchange.com/

ETL/DB testing is part of again QA, we will try to help on community for this question.
